# Как установить максимальное значение для Scrollbar?

Tags: python, tkinter, scrollbar

Делаю простой log viewer на python, использую tkinter.
Код:

```
def insert_text():
    text.delete(1.0, END)
    file_name = fd.askopenfilename()
    global f
    f = open(file_name, 'r')
    f.seek(0, 0)
    text_value = f.read(text_height)
    text.insert("end", text_value)


def move(change):
    text.delete(1.0, END)
    global f
    if int(change) > 0:
        text_value = f.read(text_height*int(change))
        text_value = text_value[text_height*-1:-1]
    else:
        f.seek(f.tell() + text_height * int(change) - text_height, 0)
        text_value = f.read(text_height)
    text.insert("end", text_value)


window = Tk()

btn_open = Button(window, text="Открыть файл", command=insert_text)
btn_open.grid(column=3, row=0)

text = Text(window, width=200, height=40)
text.grid(column=1, row=1)

scrolly = Scrollbar(command=move)
scrolly.grid(column=2, row=1)
window.mainloop()
```

Все работает, при прокрутке с помощью колесика мыши читается следующие куски кода, отображаются в Text. Однако, сама полоса прокрутки остается на месте (на самой верхушке scrollbar), а значит, я могу прокручивать свой лог только колесом мыши. Перепрыгнуть на самый конец файла невозможно.

Есть ли возможность задать максимальное значение для scrollbar, чтобы прыгнуть сразу в конец, перетащив его мышью?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При привязке текстового поля к скролбару нужно чтобы и скролбар управлял текстовым полем (в вашем случае - подгружался нужный кусок файла), и текстовое поле управляло скролбаром - устанавливалась позиция начала и конца ползунка через метод `set`. В обычной привязке этот метод передается в текстовое поле через параметр `yscroll`, например `text = Text(..., yscroll=vscroll.set)` или `text['yscroll'] = vscroll.set` (в зависимости от того, какой объект создан раньше - текстовое поле или скролбар), и объект текстового поля вызывает этот метод когда нужно. В вашем случае этот метод нужно вызывать принудительно, чтобы обновлять состояние ползунка.

Другие комментарии:

- `move` должно принимать два параметра (это видно по ошибкам, которые кидает интерпретатор в консоль), за позицию отвечает второй параметр, и его нужно приводить в `float` а не `int`, и это позиция ползунка от 0.0 до 1.0 (от 0% до 100%), а не изменение позиции.

  Позиция, куда нужно переместиться в файле, определяется как позиция ползунка (от 0.0 до 1.0) умноженная на размер файла, никакой сложной логики тут не нужно.
- `f.read(...)` подгружает указанное количество символов, но логичнее подгружать нужное количество строк через `[file.readline() for _ in range(text_height)]`
- Размер ползунка фиксированный - 10%  от общего размера полосы прокрутки (0.1 в строках `scrolly.set(0.0, 0.1)` и `scrolly.set(position, position + 0.1)`). Можно сделать установку размера в зависимости от того какая часть  (доля) файла загружена, но мне было лень - и так работает :) Но в принципе ничего не мешает это сделать.

Остальное смотрите в комментариях в коде.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.filedialog as fd
import os

text_height = 40
file = None
file_size = None


def open_file():
    global file, file_size
    
    file_name = fd.askopenfilename()
    file_size = os.path.getsize(file_name)

    if file:
        file.close()

    file = open(file_name, 'r')
    text_lines = [file.readline() for _ in range(text_height)]

    text.delete(1.0, END)
    text.insert(END, ''.join(text_lines))

    # Метод set устанавливает позицию начала и конца ползунка
    # Первоначальная позиция ползунка - в самом верху,
    # конец ползунка - на 10% (от общей высоты скролбара) ниже
    scrolly.set(0.0, 0.1)  


def move(command, position=0):
    # command - обычно строка "moveto", position - значение от "0.0" до "1.0"

    # Файл открыт?
    if file is None:
        return
    
    position = float(position)

    # Не давать прокрутить выше или ниже границ файла
    # (если продолжать тянуть вниз или вверх после того как ползунок уперся в край,
    # в функцию будут приходить значения position меньше 0 или больше 1)
    if position < 0.0:
        position = 0.0
    if position > 1.0:
        position = 1.0
    
    file.seek(file_size*position)
    if position > 0.0:
        # Если не начало файла, то считать что попали на середину строки, пропускаем ее
        try:
            file.readline()
        except UnicodeDecodeError:
            # Кидает это исключение, если переход на середину utf-8 символа
            # Чтобы корректно обрабатывать такие ситуации, нужно файл открывать в бинарном режиме,
            # и в процессе чтения текст декодировать
            pass

    text_lines = [file.readline() for _ in range(text_height)]

    text.delete(1.0, END)
    text.insert(END, ''.join(text_lines))
    
    scrolly.set(position, position + 0.1)  # Обновить позицию "ползунка"


window = Tk()

btn_open = Button(window, text="Открыть файл", command=open_file)
btn_open.grid(column=3, row=0)

text = Text(window, width=200, height=text_height+1)
text.grid(column=1, row=1)

scrolly = Scrollbar(command=move)
scrolly.grid(column=2, row=1, sticky=NS)
scrolly.set(0.0, 1.0)  # Устанавливаем первоначальную высоту "ползунка" полосы прокрутки на 100%

window.mainloop()
```